# Java FX crash when changing scene

Tags: java, javafx, runtime-error

I'm trying to make a POS using javaFX but whenever I try to change the scene it keeps crasing. Any ideas of how to fix?

Main class: https://pastebin.com/4bspSL9N

SceneManager: https://pastebin.com/SU99DVgf

OutputHelper.log() is just a `system.out.println()`

output log: https://pastebin.com/GZTPRgNp

Comment: Please paste your code here

Comment: What code? There are already pastebin links to it. Isn't that enough?

Comment: primaryStage in loadScene function is not initialized

Comment: No, pastebin links are not sufficient. You need to include the code that causes the issue (or better a [mcve]) in the question itself. External links are not guarantied to be available forever; also it's much more comfortable, if you don't need to visit links to see all the necessary details. Please [edit] the question and include the code+log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized your primaryStage in the SceneManager. Try adding `this.primaryStage = primaryStage;` in your `setup` method.

Comment: Worked, that line was probably lost while trying to reorganise my code. I didn't spot it as I was almost sure that the problem was with the setScene()

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your SceneManager class:

```
public static void loadScreen(Parent parent) throws IOException {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
       // stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
      //  stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    });
}
```

Then to Load new screen use it like :

```
String Screen = "YourScreen.fxml";
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(Screen));
SceneManager.loadScreen(root);
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

This a bit late to the party but we will post for posterity
We name all our Anchor Pane's so we know who they are ie mynamePane
Then when you click a Button to go somewhere you only need to know where you are and where you want to go

```
     private void doSEARCH() throws IOException{

    stage = (Stage)searchPane.getScene().getWindow();// pane you are ON
    viewtxPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("tableview.fxml"));// pane you are GOING TO
    Scene scene = new Scene(viewtxPane);// pane you are GOING TO
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("checkbook.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Check Book Transactions"); 
    stage.show();
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.centerOnScreen();

 }
```